# PubNub DDFileLogger and DDLog warning using Pods IOS

Tags: swift, pubnub

Started to get the warning bellow after installed PubNub with PODs. Before I had PubNub copied directly to the project and was not getting the warning.

Any idea about how to get rid of this warning?

[image]

Comment: Hi!  This may be an old version of the SDK, you definitely want PubNub **`iOS SDK 4.1+`**.

Comment: I believe I am running with the latest version of it

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!
pod "PubNub"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because CocoaLumberjack didn't follow requirements for **NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER** and newest Xcode show it as warning (about -init of superclass). You can modify Podfile and use post install hooks, to update some analyser flags to silent this warnings:

```
post_install do |installer_representation|
installer_representation.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        if target.name == "CocoaLumberjack"
          config.build_settings['GCC_WARN_INHIBIT_ALL_WARNINGS'] = 'YES'
        end
    end
end
```

end

Comment: @GuiSoySauce - if this resolves your issue, please accept the answer. Cheers!